# Git difference between two remote commits

Tags: git

Is it possible to get the difference between a commit on a remote Git server, and its parent commit without downloading the entire repository? An example of what I would like to achieve is GitHub's [.patch functionality](https://github.com/github/developer.github.com/commit/a03030dea7be744a3feff20ea29f51783f37a47f.patch), where you add `.patch` to any commit URL on GitHub.

Comment: If you view the remote commit in question in the tool's UI, are you not seeing the diff you want? (Or do you want the full textual diff instead of a visual one?) What SCM are you using? Maybe it has something like GitHub patch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git itself can only diff two commits that *Git has*.  Git works locally, on your computer.

Some servers allow you to ask *their* Git, on their server, to diff two commits that *they have (locally) on their server*.  The method by which you get some server to do this depends on the server, not on Git.

To get commits locally, you must, in general, use `git fetch`.  By default, this downloads the specified commits *and every predecessor commit:* all the history leading up to the specified commit.  Many servers won't let you download a commit unless it has some specific name—a branch or tag name, for instance—so that you are forced to download a relatively late commit (which brings all of its history) so as to get some relatively early commit, but other servers will let you download a commit by hash ID:

```
git fetch <remote-or-URL> <hash>:<name>
```

where you supply the remote-or-URL, the hash, and the name, e.g.:

```
git fetch ssh://user@example.com/path/to/repo.git a123456:refs/heads/newbranch
```

which would get you a (local) branch named `newbranch` that ends at commit `a123456` and has all the history leading up to and including that commit.

Note that you can add `--depth` to a `git fetch` command to produce a *shallow clone*, where you cut off the history after some amount of commit-graph-depth.  For instance, with `--depth 1`, you get just one commit.<sup>1</sup>

**If**—this is a pretty big if<sup>2</sup>—you can get commits by hash ID, you can combine the `--depth` trick with the above "create a new branch from a specified commit" trick to do this:

```
git fetch --depth 1 origin $hash1:refs/heads/tmp1 $hash2:refs/heads/tmp2
git diff tmp1 tmp2
git branch -D tmp1 tmp2
```

This obtains the two specified commit hash IDs (`$hash1` and `$hash2`) from the server at `origin`, then runs `git diff` on those two commits, then deletes the two temporary branch names.

(Since you asked about a commit and its parent, you could do the same with one branch name and `--depth 2`.  Use `git show` or Git's parent-hash-ID syntax to find the parent, once you have both commits.  I thought I would show the more general method, though.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Depth 1 is sometimes unwise for certain purposes, so `--depth 2` or larger is often a good idea.  A lot of SCM builders default to `--depth 50` or so, for instance, which is kind of a compromise between speed and usability.  For your *particular* case, we're working on an example where `--depth 1` could work for you, though.

<sup>2</sup>In the past, this was *not* the default.  With Git's new partial clone feature, it has become the default, though, so the number of repositories on which this trick works is increasing.

Answer (score 0):

You can always `git show <hash>` with any hash, including remote commits that you didn't checkout locally, as long as they're known to your git after any `git fetch`. That will show the commit, i.e. the diff with its parent commit.

Other things that could work for your case are `git diff <hash1> <hash2>` to see the diff between any 2 commits (regardless whether they're remote or local) and `git show remote/branch-name` to show the last commit in a remote branch.